# Issue with Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '.'.`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `Integrationstoresting.tick` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

I see.  You seem to want this:

```
SELECT e.ReceivedFrom, e.Sent, q.InstrumentId, q.LastAction
FROM integrationstorestaging.tick.Email e JOIN
     integrationstorestaging.tick.CdsIndexOptionQuote q
     ON e.EmailId=q.EmailId
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, e.Sent, GETUTCDATE()) < 3 ;
```

Your `FROM` keyword is in the wrong place.  You should study up on basic SQL syntax.